# Hibernate @Where not returning parent entity if child collection query returns no results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity

```java
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    private UUID parentId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Company.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = Fields.parentId)
    @Where(clause = "deleted_at is null")
    private List<Company> childCompanies;

    private Instant deletedAt;
    private UUID deletedBy;
}
```

The problem I am having is in the scenario when all child companies have been deleted, and calling `repository.findById(parentCompanyId)` returns an empty optional, because the join clause created by hibernate on the resulting query returns no results, which makes sense based on the query it creates, but it is not what I was expecting from this functionality.

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong? What other approach could I follow here?
Many thanks